# PHP nested Ifs are not working

Tags: php, if-statement, nested-if

I'm checking if Facebook users don't like a page. If so, the code displays the user's name and an invitation message to "Like it"; if not, it displays the "incentive landing page". However, I just get the first part: the code doesn't show the "incentive" when users hit the Like button. The code looks like this:

```
<?php if(!$like_status): ?> 
    <?php if ($me): ?>
      <div id="name">Hola <?php echo $me['first_name']; ?></div> //Everything works fine.  
    <?php endif; ?>
     // Display graphics... Everything works fine.
<?php else : ?>
     //Page with the incentive... This does not work when the nested if is present.
<?php endif; ?>
```

If I get rid of the nested if (the one that displays the user's name), everything works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: @Charles Sprayberry `:` is perfectly fine. @Byktor what is the value of the like_status;

Comment: LOL @ Charles :) Read this bro: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: Yes, I got to the alternative syntax.  I still say the `:` should be `{}`.  To me, that looks hideous :)

Comment: This is the recommended syntax for PHP when code is placed within HTML syntax in a view in most MVC frameworks.

Comment: Charles: I tried both Like values: false and true.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? In 5.3.3 your snippet works fine.

Comment: Will it work at your machine if you remove a space after `else`? E.g. `else:`

Comment: @sanmai My problem is when Facebook processes the code. (Is this could be a Facebook bug? I'll check it.) Without the nested if to display the user's name, the if else code works fine; with it, the else section does not work.

Comment: Replace the Facebook code with something else. If it works, blame Facebook.

Comment: I'm still working on this out of curiosity, @Sanmai. I am not inclined to blame FB yet, since the code works perfectly fine in FF, Chrome, and IE9. The problem is IE7-8.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing your semicolon after the endif's

```
<?php if(!$like_status): ?>   
    <?php if ($me): ?>
      // Display user's name... Everything works fine.  
    <?php endif; ?>
     // Display graphics... Everything works fine.
<?php else: ?>
     //Page with the incentive... This does not work when the nested if is present.
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I already tried the semicolon after the endif... didn't work. I'll recheck it, just in case, and let you know.... Rechecked it and it didn't work.

Comment: I'm guessing there is an error in that code you're not showing us ;) Code works fine, just tested it: `$like_status = true;
        if(empty($like_status)):
            if(!empty($me)):
                echo 'name';
            endif;
            echo 'graphics';
        else:
            echo 'incentive';
        endif;`  outputs "incentive"

Comment: I added the three critical lines.

Comment: No spamimng, @Ibu... I just wanted @AlienWebguy to see the result. I deleted the link a few minutes later.

Comment: Thank you everybody. I just rewrote the code *no nested if* and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody is facing the same problem, I found the solution: for some reason IE 7-8 doesn't like the variable $me and the call to the API('/me') in the same context. I just changed the name of the variable and everything works fine in FF, Chrome, and IE 7-9.